# Reducing features to 2 by PCA confusion Matlab

Tags: feature-selection, pca, matlab

I am trying to reduce $500$ features to $2$ as an assignment. I wrote the following code and I am deeply concerned if it is true as when I plot it on the graph it does not look good. It should look good as I have to apply cluster algorithm to is as a next step. Can you help me pls?

```
X = data;

X = bsxfun(@minus,X,mean(X));  %%standardize

CM = transpose(X)*X;  %%coveriance matrix is calculated

[V,D] = eig(CM);
eigenvalues = zeros(1,306);

for k = 1:306
    eigenvalues(1,k) = D(k,k);
end

sortedEigenValues = sort(eigenvalues,'descend');  %%eigenvalues are sorted
sortedEigenVectors = zeros(306,306);

for k=1:306  %%eigenvectors are sorted according to eigenvalues
    for l=1:306
        if sortedEigenValues(1,k) == D(l,l)
            sortedEigenVectors(:,k) = V(:,l);    
        end
    end
end
projectionMatrix = sortedEigenVectors(:,1:2); %% first to columns of sortedEigenVectors matrix are taken to create projection matrix
projectedMatrix = CM*projectionMatrix; %%projectedMatrix is what I am intending to use.

figure
stem(projectedMatrix(:,1),projectedMatrix(:,2)); %%plotting altogether
```

I have found eigenvalues and sort them and also sort eigenvectors and I take first $2$ eigenvectors and multiply it with the coveriance matrix and hope that this new matrix is what I am supposed to cluster, but I am very confused. Can you give some feedback?

Answer (score 0):

After obtaining the principal component, you should compute $XW$ rather than $X^TXW$ where $W$ is the principal component.

Remark about computation efficiency: As you sort the eigenvalues, you could have obtained the corresponding permutation indices.